# Appropriate to clarify conceptual understanding on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

As a relatively new developer, I often have intuitions of rudimentary understandings of various concepts (can be language-specific or broad enough to cover the entire domain of "programming").  I am unsure if StackOverflow is the right place to clarify these thoughts.

For instance, I think I understand the idea of a "controller" in the MVC pattern as implemented by Rails, but my understanding does not cover edge cases (a tableless model, a partial view) very well.  Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place to flesh out my understanding or is that better suited for forums/railscast?

On the one hand, I definitely have a **minimal understanding** and am looking to expand upon it.  Additionally, I understand SO is intended to be a **repository of knowledge**, and I feel that my question has value to those who would come after me, assuming formal documentation remains at the same level.

On the other hand, the question is fairly **specific** (perhaps to the point of being too specific) and I feel like it may be interpreted as **inviting discussion**, though that is not my intention- my ideal is a domain expert swoops in, says "Controllers Do This!" and swoops out with his upvotes and little controversy.

Is SO the right place for questions of this type?  Programmers.stackexchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow is for *specific* programming problems, not conceptual problems at a higher level.

Programmers is for conceptual questions, or "whiteboard" questions.

Comment: A valid point, and one that helps me understand.  Obviously, that response leads to a question of "what is **specific** and what is **too localized**, but that is both its own question and something I'm willing to leave to users' experience.

Does an SE site exist for the type of question I'm discussing then?  Or is it, as I say, best left to domain-specific forums?

Comment: @ABMagil I don't understand very well what it is you're specific example question actually is.  It sounds like it might be too broad; explaining an entire concept, when it's not a very simple concept, is likely too much for any SO site.  If you can focus it down to the point that you feel it could be answered in a paragraph or two, then there could perhaps be a place for it.

Comment: I have a very specific example in my head but I don't feel its inclusion here would benefit my MSO question, as it is fairly complex.  Does a method within (M)SO exist to "take this offline" or otherwise clarify before cluttering SE?  Or do I simply post my question on SO and link it here?  That feels like jumping the gun of my MSO question.

Comment: As per this answer, your question likely doesn't belong on SO at all.  It probably belongs on Programmers.  While you can potentially use the meta sites to ask for help in forming a question, generally it's easiest to just ask the question and simply be diligent in responding to comments indicating how your question should be improved.